# Google Analytics - gapi - tableID

Tags: google-analytics

i'm working on google analytics and try to get some data from analytics. What i want is retrieving all table id and name from analytics but really dont know how to do. i spend hours in Google . Is there a way to do that ?

[image]

i want to take these all table like Izlesene.com  KurtlarVadisi - Mobil uygulama  and their ids how can i retrieve them ?

then i want to put them to my html

```
<td width="138"><strong>Kanal Adı</strong>
    <td width="150"><b>Kategori Adı</b></td>
    <td width="130"><p><strong>Event Adı</strong></td>
    <td width="145"><strong>Toplam</strong>;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get that data out via the [Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html).

Currently there's no UI to get this data out that I'm aware of.

You can play with it in the Google API's Explorer.

- Go to the [Google API's Explorer](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=analytics&_v=v3&_m=management.profiles.list&accountId=~all&webPropertyId=~all).
- Look for the Analytics v3 API.
- Select the management.profiles.list method.
- Click the authorization button on top right
- authorize the API
- Fill both required fields with `~all`
- Click Execute

You will get a JSON feed with the data you want. The API's explorer are just a toy to play with the API though. You better off writing your own script to query it and get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleAllAccounts(results) {    
    if (!results.code) {
        if (results && results.items && results.items.length) {
            // Get the first Google Analytics account
            var AccountIds = new Array();            
            for(var i=0 ;i<results.items.length;i++){
                AccountIds[i] = results.items[i].id;
            }
            queryAllProfiles(AccountIds,results.items.length);
        } else {
            console.log('No accounts found for this user.')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('There was an error querying accounts: ' + results.message);
    }
}

function queryAllProfiles(accountId,count) {
    console.log('Querying Profiles.');
    var sel = document.getElementById('managementProfiles');
    var opt = null;
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++){              
        gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list({
            'accountId': accountId[i]
        }).execute(function fn(results){
            for(var j=0;j<results.items.length;j++){              
                gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
                    'accountId': results.items[j].accountId,
                    'webPropertyId': results.items[j].id
                }).execute(function innertwo(profiles_results){
                    if (!profiles_results.code) {
                        if (profiles_results && profiles_results.items && profiles_results.items.length) {
                            opt = document.createElement('option');
                            opt.value = 'ga:'+profiles_results.items[0].id;
                            opt.innerHTML = profiles_results.items[0].name;
                            sel.appendChild(opt);                                                      
                        } 
                    }              
                }) 
            }
        })     
    }
    sel.style.display ="block" ;
}


In your google analyticle javascript file put these two function these function retrive all management profiles of any google analyticle account authenticated by google
```